# JavaSQLException - ORA-0933: command not properly ended

Tags: java, sql

I'm confused about the SQL String query in method below. It shows absolutely correct and despite who rows created in oracle database, threw the following exception: ORA-0933: command not properly ended. I try to find the solution but without result.

What is going wrong? Can you help me?

Thank you in advance and sorry for any bad English.

```
public void insertMemberAction() {

     String query = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS VALUES(" + jMnoTxt.getText() + ", '" + 
          jLastnameTxt.getText() + "', '"  + jFirstnameTxt.getText() + "', '" + 
          jAddressTxt.getText() + "', '"   + jRegistrationDateTxt.getText() + "')";

        java.sql.Statement insertStmt;

        try {

            insertStmt = DvdClubJFrame.con.createStatement();
            insertStmt.executeUpdate(query);
            insertStmt.close();

        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());

        }

}
```

Comment: try adding a ';' at the end

Comment: You should be using prepared statements mate

Comment: As Freaky Thommi says, try adding a semi-colon at the end of the query. Also, why is the first value being passed without the quotes?

Comment: And how `query` value looks before `executeUpdate()` call? You could miss some `'` or one of your parameters have `'` inside its own value or `jMnoTxt` is empty string? As other said -- use `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @DanTemple: That's wrong. If you pass a `;` as part of the String to `Statement.executeUpdate()` it will result in an "illegal character" error.

Comment: @Steven: print out the generated SQL statement and you'll probably see the error for yourself. Apart from the suggestion to use a `PreparedStatement` instead, you should also qualify the columns for the insert statement: `insert into members (mno, lastname, firstname, ...) values (?, ?, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, for the direct answers. The semi-colon at the end is wrong. I tryed it. Ok, about jMnoTxt, this text field contains only numeric values. The type is int in sql.

Answer (score 1):

Use PreparedStatements, or escape your parameters using apache common's `StringEscapeUtils`

Comment: Only use PreparedStatement. If you escape the parameter, you will forget one.

Comment: Yes I agree, PreparedStatement is best practice.

Comment: Yep prepared statements all the way, dont dick around with statements very insecure, unless you love fixing SQL injection hacks